# Original paper of Christiaan Huygens discussing moment of inertia

Tags: history, moment-of-inertia, specific-reference

As far as I know, it was Christiaan Huygens who first proposed the concept of the $\text{moment of inertia}^1$. Where can I find that paper/book where he first mentioned it? It is not mentioned in the resource referenced.

$^1$Harry Varvoglis, *History and Evolution of Concepts in Physics*

Comment: Probably a better fit for [hsm.se]

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine Yeah I was unsure between PSE and HSM myself but since PSE offers the tag of "specific-reference" and it really isn't about the history of moment of inertia I thought PSE would be better.

Comment: Perhaps this wikipedia article helps. Check out ref. 1. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia

Comment: References in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiaan_Huygens#Laws_of_motion,_impact,_and_gravitation may be useful, particularly Gabbey, Alan (1980). Huygens and mechanics. In H.J.M. Bos, M.J.S. Rudwick, H.A.M. Snelders, & R.P.W. Visser (Eds.), Studies on Christiaan Huygens (pp. 166-199). Swets & Zeitlinger B.V.